# React: Chartjs won't show data from Flask backend

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flask

I have built a web app that uses a Flask backend and React frontend, I am very new to React so my knowledge is limited. I want to pass two lists of data from the backend to the frontend and then display them using Chartjs.

The frontend receives the data, the chart is displayed but doesn't get populated with the data.

The output displayed looks like this:

---

1,2,3,4,5,6

*CHART WITH NO DATA*

---

Flask App:

```
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/api", methods=['GET'])
def get_data():
    return jsonify({"y": [1, 2, 3, 2, 3, 4],             
                    "x": [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
                    }
                   )
```

React frontend:

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import Chart from "chart.js";


export default function CardLineChart() {
  const [x, setX] = useState([]);
  const [y, setY] = useState([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch('/api')
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        setY(data.y);
        setX(data.x);
    });
    
    let config = {
      type: "line",
      data: {
        labels: X,
        datasets: [
          {
            label: new Date().getFullYear(),
            backgroundColor: "rgb(252,228,0,0.7)",
            borderColor: "rgb(252,228,0,0.9)",
            data: Y,
          },
        ],
      },
      options: {
        maintainAspectRatio: false,
        responsive: true,
        title: {
          display: false,
          text: "Orders Chart",
        },
        tooltips: {
          mode: "index",
          intersect: false,
        },
        hover: {
          mode: "nearest",
          intersect: true,
        },
        scales: {

          xAxes: [
            {
              display: false,
              scaleLabel: {
                display: false,
                labelString: "Month",
              },
              gridLines: {
                display: false,
                color: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
                zeroLineColor: "rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)",
              },
            },
          ],

          yAxes: [
            {
              display: true,
              scaleLabel: {
                display: false,
                labelString: "Value",
              },
              ticks: {
                suggestedMin: 0,
              },
              gridLines: {
                drawBorder: false,
                lineWidth: 0.4,
                color: "rgba(33, 37, 41, 0.2)",
                zeroLineColor: "rgba(33, 37, 41, 0.15)",
              },
            },
          ],
        },
      },
    };
    var ctx = document.getElementById("line-chart").getContext("2d");
    window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);
  }, []);
  return (
    <>
      <p>{x}</p>
      <div className="relative flex flex-col min-w-0 break-words bg-white w-full mb-4 rounded">
        <div className="p-4 flex-auto">
          {/* Chart */}
          <div className="relative h-250-px">
            <canvas id="line-chart"></canvas>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This code breaks a few fundamental React rules.

First of all, sirens should sound when directly manipulating the DOM when writing React components. 99.9% of the time there's a better way. Prefer [refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) instead of `document.getElementById("line-chart")`.

`window.myLine = new Chart(ctx, config);` is also poor practice. This breaks out of React, sticking data globally on the window, which is almost certainy a hack. It's unclear why `window.line` was thought to be necessary, but if the chart is needed elsewhere in the component tree, either consider lifting state up, using a reducer or context rather than bypassing React.

Secondly, `setState` and `fetch` are not synchronous. Notwithstanding using `X` (capitalized) rather than `x` (lowercase), this pattern will always fail:

```js
() => {
  fetch('/api/').then(data => {
    setX(data.x);
    setY(data.y);
    // executes last
  );

  // trying to use use x and y here will fail
})();
```

Any code in place of the commented line will execute synchronously before the `fetch` promise has a chance to resolve in the `then` block. Furthermore, state setting is asynchronous as well, so there's a double whammy (triple if the capitalization typo counts). This pattern is also wrong:

```js
() => {
  setX(data.x); // state setting is async, executes last
  setY(data.y);

  // trying to use use x and y here will fail
})();
```

Here's a simple demonstration you can adapt to your use case. A potentially better design is to keep the data fetching in the parent and move the chart to a subcomponent that's conditionally rendered, avoiding the ref and extra effect.

```js
const {useEffect, useRef, useState} = React;

// Mocks for demonstration
class Chart {
  constructor(canvas, {x, y}) {
    canvas.getContext("2d")
      .fillText(`${x[0]} ${y[0]}`, 40, 40);
  }
}
fetch = () => Promise.resolve({
  json: () => Promise.resolve({x: [42], y: [1]})
});
//

const CardLineChart = () => {
  const [x, setX] = useState([]);
  const [y, setY] = useState([]);
  const [chart, setChart] = useState(null);
  const canvas = useRef(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    fetch("/api")
      .then(res => res.json())
      .then(data => {
        setX(data.x);
        setY(data.y);
      });
  }, []);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (x.length && y.length) {
      const config = {x, y};
      setChart(new Chart(canvas.current, config));
    }
  }, [x, y]);

  return (
    <canvas ref={canvas}></canvas>
  );
};

ReactDOM.createRoot(document.querySelector("#app"))
  .render(<CardLineChart />);
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@18/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@18/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="app"></div>
```